# Adding disclaimer page to document

Tags: minipage, thesis, report

I would like to add the disclaimer page to my document. When I added the command `\disclaimer` before the abstract, I got the error:

> "! Undefined control sequence. l.104 \disclaimer".

The code:

```
\documentclass[abstract=on,ngerman,12pt,a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\end{titlepage}    

\disclaimer{The contents of this report...}
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

with the result:
[image]

Comment: the report class does not have a `\disclaimer` command (or an `abstract=on` option), are you looking at the documentation of a different class file?

Comment: Thanks.Maybe! I don't know what should I do. It is a Masterthesis. Is the report class not approapraite?

Comment: I removed `abstrat=on`

Comment: @JavaDeveloper: Can you provide an example of what this "disclaimer page" should look like?

Comment: It's an appropriate class, but you can't just make up command names and expect them to do something.

Comment: I added a picture of that page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you probably need this just once why not simply

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\end{titlepage}

\textbf{Disclaimer}

\vspace{0.2in} % if you wish

The contents of this report...

\newpage % if you wish

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```